# How to compare two arrays using lodash (the order matters)

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
var arr1=[3,4,5,6,7,1,9];
var arr2=[1,3,4,6,7,5,9];
```

I want to compare arr2 to arr1. But the methods `difference()` and `intersection()` only seem to find if the two arrays have the same elements or not. I want to compare the two arrays spot by spot like arr1[0] to arr2[0], arr1[1] to arr2[1]. And it should show:

```
intersection: 6,7,9
difference: 1,3,4,5
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what about `isEqual`?

Comment: What is the problem? You can iterate and compare.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not simply to determine if the two arrays are the same or not. Partial identical is also needed to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in lodash by zipping both arrays, filtering, and than taking the last item of each pair. The comperator for intersection is that the pair is equal. The comperator for difference is that the pair are not equal.

```js
const arr1 = [3,4,5,6,7,1,9];
const arr2 = [1,3,4,6,7,5,9];

const compare = (comperator) => (arr1, arr2) => 
  _.zip(arr1, arr2)
  .filter(comperator)
  .map(_.last);

const eq = _.spread(_.eq);

const intersection = compare(eq);
  
const difference = compare(_.negate(eq));

console.log('intersection ', intersection(arr1, arr2));
console.log('difference ', difference(arr1, arr2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use xor from lodash and it will return an empty array if the arrays have the same elements.

```
const a1= ['a', 'b', 'd']
const a2= ['d', 'b', 'a']
 
_.xor(a1, a2).length;//0
```

Comment: This doesn't follow the question as it has to be in order

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate both arrays in parallel and sort them into two seperate Sets:

```
 function* parallel(a, b) {
   for(let i = 0; i < a.length || i < b.length; i++)
     yield [ a[i], b[i] ];
 }

 const intersection = new Set, 
    difference = new Set;

 for(const [a, b] of parallel(arr1, arr2)) {
   if(a === b) 
     intersection.add(a);
   else
      difference.add(a).add(b);
 }

 console.log([...intersection], [...difference]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This also could be solved with `reduce`:

```js
var arr1 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 9];
var arr2 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 9];

const f = (a, b) => b.reduce((r,c,i) => (a[i] == c ? 
  r.intersection.push(c) : 
  r.difference.push(c), r), {intersection: [], difference: []})

console.log(f(arr1, arr2))
```

Where you start with a pre-set accumulator object and compare each array value using the index.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write your own utility function that checks equality of the sequence? Something like:

```
export function sequenceEqual<T>(firstSequence: T[], secondSequence: T[]): boolean {
    if(!firstSequence || !secondSequence) return false;
    return firstSequence.every(
        (d, i) => d === secondSequence[i]
    );
}
```

This way you can just return boolean. There is no need to perform an extra step to check if the code returned some array or number or whatever, what is length of the returned type, which number it is etc. You just ask are my sequences equal and get true or false.

One more benefit is that you are not dependent on some library. Unless they have sequenceEqual so that you don't have to write from scratch, just call it, but I couldn't find it yet in Lodash.